# Twilio incoming call with <conference> not ringing to agent twilio.device.incoming

Tags: javascript, twilio, mute, twilio-conference

In my simple scenario, single calls to single-agent works perfectly fine with Twilio.device.incoming.

Once it comes to handle many incoming calls to many available agents with hold/unhold feature. Everyone it is recommended to use <conference>. after using conference it is putting customer into a conference call with waitUrl music but how the agent will receive an **incoming ring** and can accept this new call with hold/unhold feature.

I am using PHP and Javascript SDK. it is using Twilio.Device.incoming.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you receive the incoming webhook and respond by placing the caller into a conference, you should also place a new outbound call to your agent to have them join the conference too.

You can do this with the [conference participants resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource?code-sample=code-create-a-conference-participant&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x):

```php
$participant = $twilio->conferences("CONFERENCE_NAME")
                      ->participants
                      ->create("YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER", "AGENT_ADDRESS");
```